# Python xlsxwriter write_rich_string and highlight

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I use `xlsxwriter` to generate an `excel` report. I would like to underline a part of the text thanks to the `write_rich_string` method.

```
format = {
    'text': self.formats.result,
    'difference': self.formats.difference_result
}
args = [self.current_line, _column]
for diff in _diff:
    args.append(format.get(diff.get('kind')))
    args.append(diff.get('text'))
args.append(self.formats.result)
self.worksheet.write_rich_string(*args)
```

where these formats:

```
self.difference_result = self.workbook.add_format()
self.difference_result.set_font_color('yellow')
self.difference_result.set_fg_color('red')

self.result = self.workbook.add_format()
self.result.set_align('top')
self.result.set_text_wrap()
self.result.set_border(1)
self.result.set_border_color('gray')
```

My problem is that the text is in yellow but not highligh in red. Is this possible with xlsxwriter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible with xlsxwriter?

In general if the formatting is possible in Excel it is possible in XlsxWriter since it supports all of Excel's cell formatting.

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do isn't possible in Excel. From the [`write_rich_string()` docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-rich-string):

> In Excel only the font properties of the format such as font name, style, size, underline, color and effects are applied to the string fragments in a rich string. Other features such as border, background, text wrap and alignment must be applied to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import xlsxwriter
outfile  = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet    = outfile.add_worksheet()
underlin = outfile.add_format({'underline': True})
sheet.write_rich_string(0,0,"This text as usual, ",underlin,"this underlined, ","and this as usual")
outfile.close()
```